# Quickest way to delete lots of small files with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder, with 24 sub folders, one for each hour.
Each subfolder contains at least 100,000 txt files, each up to 10kb in size.

I am trying to find the quickest way to delete the folder, all sub folders and files.

At the moment I am just using:

```
Remove-Item -path $Folder.FullName -Recurse -Force
```

However this seems to be quite time consuming.
Whats the quickest way to delete all of these using powershell?

Comment: the fastest way i have used is to mirror a blank source dir to the "delete this dir tree" using `robocopy`. mirroring "empty dir" is amazingly fast - especially if you disable screen output ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the .NET `.Delete()` method.

```
[System.IO.Directory]::Delete($folder.Fullname,$true)
```

**Explanation:**

Often times, using the .NET methods are faster for file and folder operations than the seemingly equivalent PowerShell commands. Here we are using the `.Delete(String,Boolean)` variant. String represents the full path of want you want deleted. Boolean represents the True or False value for recursion (`$true` being yes to recursion). Without recursion, the directories would need to be empty before they could be deleted.

See [Directory.Delete Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_Delete_System_String_System_Boolean_) for more information.

Comment: And you think this would be faster? I will try it out.

Comment: I do believe it will. The unanswered question is will it be fast enough to meet your requirements?

Comment: I've read your explanation and that all makes sense so me. I have just implemented it, will give it an hour and see how much its managed to get through. but if there is an even faster route, I would obviously prefer that. This is a scheduled task that will run on a Server every morning to clear out logs that are over a month old. Ideally I would like it to complete in under an hour, but that target seems a bit stretched.

Comment: So this has turned out to be too slow, but I am now trying the idea of generating a list of all files, deleting each file, then deleting the hour folder. Once all hour folders have been deleted, delete the date folder, and this seems to be considerably quicker.

Comment: Try it in C#.  You can do it in a powershell script with add-type.